# Apache TomCat Deny Access to File

Tags: tomcat, configuration, url-rewriting

i want to deny access to some files on the Apache Tomcat server.
I read documentation/articles/e.t.c., all write about writing web.xml, but i do it, at tomcat_home/conf directory, reboot TomCat server and nothing happened. Help me please !

I have added inside web-app tag:

```
     <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <url-pattern>/sample</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
 <auth-constraint>
<role-name>managers</role-name>

</auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
```